# What is the best way to deploy custom metadata to SharePoint?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create a SharePoint application that logs to ULS using a set of custom diagnostic logging areas and categories.  I'm using the SharePoint Guidance Library to provision the areas and categories through a feature event receiver in a farm feature, but I need a way to deploy a set of areas and categories with my solution that would allow one to update the areas and categories without requiring a rebuild of the solutions that rely on them.  So:

1. I want to be able to refer to the areas and categories with permanent references that will pull in content at runtime
2. I want to deploy the areas/categories in a localizable form
3. I want to be able to update or add to the area/category names and severity levels without a rebuil

My first approach was to build out a set of static classes with custom attributes so that I could use reflection to enumerate the areas and categories.  This satisfied #1, but then I realized that I also wanted #2 and #3.

My next approach was to create a simple XML schema that would allow me to specify in XML a set of areas (one per file), and then embed those XML files in a resource file to be deployed with my solution.  I'm not so sure this is going to be what I want in the long run, but I'm not sure of another good way to do this short of just dumping XML files in the 14 hive (ugh).

Has anyone else got a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always store the XML in the property bag of the Farm. You will be able to use property names to specify a configuration for each locale as well and fall back to a default if it isn't found.